# ASP.NET: how to reload page when user clicks on browser's back button

Tags: asp.net, .net

I have a Grid with a list of orders, when the user clicks on an icon in the row it takes him to the order detail. 
Problem is if he wants to go back to the list with the back button to the orders list then buttons dont work because events are not binded to their methods as i figured out...
So when he goes back and wants to click on another order, it loads back up the first order detail he got in :S

How can i capture the "going back" to reload the site?

I have it now like this, with no success:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInit(e);
    this.Load += new EventHandler(Page_Load);
}
```

And in the Page_Load method i do what i want to do:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.GridView1.RowDataBound += 
         new GridViewRowEventHandler(GridView1_RowDataBound);
    this.GridView2.RowDataBound += 
         new GridViewRowEventHandler(GridView1_RowDataBound);
    this.GridView1.Sorting += 
         new GridViewSortEventHandler(OnProductsSorting);
    this.GridView1.PageIndexChanging += 
         new GridViewPageEventHandler(OnProductsPageIndexChanging);
    this.GridView2.PageIndexChanging += 
         new GridViewPageEventHandler(OnProductsPageIndexChanging2);
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you should focus your efforts on disallowing pages to be cached, instead of trying to "refresh" a stale page.

Comment: It would be better to open order details in a popup while leaving the orders page open in the background. In this way, you would not need to worry about going back.